# Azure Data Factory v2 - wrong year copying from parquet to SQL DB

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, parquet, azure-data-factory

I'm having a weird issue with Azure Data Factory v2. There's a Spark Job which is running and producing parquet files as output, an ADFv2 copy activity then takes the output parquet and copies the data into an Azure SQL Database. All is working fine except for dates! When the data lands in SQL the year is 1969 years out. So todays date (2018-11-22) would land as 3987-11-22.

I've tried changing the source and destination types between Date, DateTime, DateTimeOffset and String but with no success. At the moment I'm correcting the dates in the database but this is not really ideal.

I've opened the source parquet files using Parquet Viewer, Spark and Python (desktop) and they all correctly show the year as 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to parquet date type definition, 
https://drill.apache.org/docs/parquet-format/#sql-types-to-parquet-logical-types
The date is stored as "the number of days from the Unix epoch, **1 January 1970**"

And ADF is using .net type doing the transformation. According to .net type definition, Time values are measured in 100-nanosecond units called ticks. A particular date is the number of ticks since 12:00 midnight, **January 1, 000**1 A.D. (C.E.) 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=netframework-4.7.2

Seems extra 1969 is added for this reason. But not sure whether is this a bug. What is your parquet data type? is it Date? and what is the sql data type?
Could you provide the copy activity run id? Or maybe some parquet sample data?

Comment: Thanks for that. The datatype in the DataFrame in Databricks is java.sql.Date and it is targeting a DateTime field in the SQL database.

I've created a repo over at github which contains a dotnetcore console app using parquet.net which reads a sample file created in Databricks. It has a java.sql.Date and and java.sql.Timestamp field. The parquet file is in the repo and in the /media directory there's some screenshots from Python, Parquet Viewer, Databricks, ADF and the output of the console app.

https://github.com/dazfuller/adf-parquet-date-issue

Comment: Hi @daz-fuller, this is a known issue and the fix is deploying now. This may take a couple of days. Please try later to confirm if the issue is fixed.

Comment: I just spotted it last night when the SQL fix I implemented overflowed the type :) Thanks for resolving this so quickly

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Parquet encoding definitions](https://github.com/apache/parquet-format/blob/master/Encodings.md),no `Date, DateTime, DateTimeOffset and String` format exist,so you do not need to try with these formats.

Based on this [Data type mapping for Parquet files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#data-type-mapping-for-parquet-files) in Azure Data Factory:

[image]

The `DateTimeOffset` format corresponds to `Int96`,I suggest you trying this transmission on the source of parquet file.

Comment: The parquet in this example can't change and Int96 isn't an option for the dataset. Changing the dataset type to Timespan would give the closest approximation to the underlying value